# A question about a family of seminorms inducing topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a question from Rudin's *Functional Analysis*. The theorem's statement and the proof go like the following.

> [image]

In the proof, it says "a set $A \subset X$ to be open if and only if $A$ is a union of translates of members of $\mathscr{B}$". However, for the simplest case,  given two open sets $\big( x+V(p,1/n) \big)$and $\big(y+V(q,1/m)\big)$, their intersection is open?

In other words, can we find another translate of a member of $\mathscr{B}$ which contained in  $\big(x+V(p,1/n)\big) \cap \big(y+V(q,1/m)\big)$? I think it is equivalent to the statement that the translates of every member of $\mathscr{B}$ are the base of a topology.

I'd appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $(x+V(p,1/n))\cap(y+V(q,1/m))$ is nonempty and let $$
z\in(x+V(p,1/n))\cap(y+V(q,1/m)),
$$ 
that is,
$$
p(z-x)<1/n,\qquad q(z-y)<1/m.
$$
There exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that 
$$
p(z-x)+\varepsilon<1/n,\qquad q(z-y)+\varepsilon<1/m.
$$
Hence, if $\xi\in z+\{p<\varepsilon\}\cap\{q<\varepsilon\}$ then
$$
p(\xi-x)<p(\xi-z)+p(z-x)<\varepsilon+p(z-x)<1/n,
$$
and
$$
q(\xi-y)<q(\xi-z)+q(z-y)<\varepsilon+q(z-y)<1/m,
$$
meaning that
$$
\xi\in(x+V(p,1/n))\cap(y+V(q,1/m)).
$$

*Note*: Another answer appeared while I was writing this answer. I leave it here since it has a tiny bit more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I had tried a similar way, but I failed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $z\in U:=(x+V(p,n))\cap (y+V(q,m))$ and choose $N> (\frac{1}{n}-p(z-x))^{-1}+(\frac{1}{m}-q(z-y))^{-1}$. Then, for any $w\in z+V(p,N)\cap V(q,N)$, we have $p(w-x)\leq p(w-z)+p(z-x)<\frac{1}{n}$. Similarly, we have $q(w-y)<\frac{1}{m}$. This establishes that $z+V(p,N)\cap V(q,n)\subseteq U$. Since $z$ was arbitrary, we get that $U$ is, indeed, open in the proposed topology.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I started with a similar argument, but I couldn't finish it. Thanks!